# VID layout pane supporting multiple face creations [rebol2]

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Please consider this simple rebol2 code to illustrate my problem:

```
REBOL []
a: make face [
    offset: 0x0
    color: yellow
    size: 20x20
]
b: make face [
    offset: 0x0
    color: red
    size: 60x60
    pane: reduce [
        make a [offset: 0x0]
        make a [offset: 10x10]
        make a [offset: 10x20]
    ]
]
view layout [
    box 200x200 white with [
        pane: reduce [
            make b [offset: 0x30] ;; one 'instance' of b
        ]
    ]
]
```

The main point here is for a layout (or face) to be able to display a bunch of faces inside its pane block in such a manner that multiple creations of the same face (`b` in this case) should be possible. The shown code works well, and the only *instance* (let me call it this way) of `b` is displayed as it should be.

But now suppose I change the code so I have, say, 2 *instances* of `b`:

```
view  layout [
    box 200x200 white with [
        pane: reduce [
            make b [offset: 0x30]
            make b [offset: 0x10]
        ]
    ]
]
```

At this point I get the error

```
** Script Error: Face object reused (in more than one pane): none
** Where: view
** Near: show scr-face
if new [do-events]
```

From the message I presume here that face `b` is somehow getting reused and messing exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I've done lots of research on this and at some point I found that it is possible to get around it by cloning (using `make`) the face to be passed to `pane`; that's what I thought I was doing, but with no success at all.

Given this scenario, my question is: how can I go about to solve this? is rebol2 ok to provide this "face-instantiation" or it is best to try something else outside rebol2 (perhaps rebol3)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is already pointed out the problem is that `a` is reused, not `b`!

the layout function uses a field called `init` for handling things like this. As I understand it `init` is first bound to the face and then called with `do` after the face itself is instantiated (at least partially).

In this case I would be using the `style` command in layout (still partially using face object `a` )

```
view layout [
    style
        bb box 60x60
        with [
            append init [
                pane reduce [
                    make a [offset: 0x0]
                    make a [offset: 10x10]
                    make a [offset: 10x20]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    panel 200x200 white [
        at 30x0 bb
        at 0x0  bb
    ]
]
```

The other alternative, a bit more similar to your would be:

```
b: make face [
    offset: 0x0
    color: red
    size: 60x60
    init: [
        pane: reduce [
            make a [offset: 0x0]
            make a [offset: 10x10]
            make a [offset: 10x20]
        ]
    ]
]
view layout [
    box 200x200
    with [
        append init [
            pane: reduce [
                make b [ offset: 0x0 do init ]
                make b [ offset: 0x60 do init ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
 ]
```

Note that `init` is manually called within the make clause in this case. I'm not all sure why it is needed.
Finally the everything could elegantly be solved with style

```
view layout [
    style a box yellow 20x20
    style b panel red 60x60 [
        at 0x0 a   ; we can in this style use the just defined a style
        at 10x10 a
        at 10x20 a
    ]
    at 0x0 b
    at 0x60 b
]
```

Comment: Second approach worked best for my problem and it was straightforward/transparent for what I was intending to build upon next with this code. Thank you for posting :D

Answer (score 3):

Rebol2 is definitely ok to do this.

When you MAKE b second time you are using the same instance of a. That is the problem.

You can write a function that creates necessary faces and append them to a block and return.
Don't forget to create 'a (first face) every time.

Additionally, check for the iterated faces in the documentation.

Here I added an example:

```
REBOL []
make-pane: func [ofst [pair! block!] /local a b faces] [
    a: make face [
        offset: 0x0
        color: yellow
        size: 20x20
    ]
    faces: copy []
    either block? ofst [
        foreach o ofst [
            append faces make a [offset: o]
        ]
    ] [
        append faces make a [offset: ofst]
    ]
    b: make face [
        offset: 0x0
        color: red
        size: 60x60
        pane: faces
    ]
]

view  layout [
    box 200x200 white with [
        pane: make-pane [5x30 0x10 20x5]
    ]
]
```

You can change the function to get more parameters to change color and other facets as well.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code and for the great insights, specially on iterated faces. I am currently looking into those, which I think (from what I read so far) suits me a bit better. I intend to play around a bit and then return whatever code I've written in a reply post for the sake of research sharing. Thanks again :D

Comment: Iterated faces are a bit difficult to use and there is no enough documantation about it. But it is useful for grid / table style UI elements.

Comment: sorry, endo64; Changed my accepted answer, although your answer provided me with great insights.

Answer (score 0):

I've said on a comment that I would get back to share my findings and I think I got something interesting. As well pointed out by @endo64, iterated faces are tricky and perhaps not best suited to what I intended to do when I first asked the question - to achieve a simple/straigthforward way to instantiate objects thru panels.

I came up with the code bellow, which implements a kind of *instantiator*. It was inspired in part by the *face-maker* approach of @endo64 along with some tinkering with iterated faces. This *instantiator* has a core limitation, which is not accepting multiple types of objects being passed to the *constructor* to be created at same pane.

Anyway, I found it was an interesting exercise and I would like to post it here in case it could be useful to someone.

---

I use the same code from the question, now solving/circumventing the limitation of creating multiple `b` objects inside the main layout pane. `a` and `b` now hold an `instantiator` object, which receives an object to create inside its pane and a block of positions (pair offsets) where objects should be placed.

```
a: make face [
    offset: 0x0
    color: yellow
    size: 30x20
]

b: make face [
    offset: 0x0
    color: red
    size: 100x100
    inst_b: _instantiator/new reduce a [10x10 10x70 80x80 30x30] ; instantiator here  
    pane: get in inst_b 'pane_function
]
```

The *instantiator* code is:

```
_instantiator: make object! [
    _obj: copy []
    _offsets: copy []

    new: func [
        obj [object!] "object to create inside pane"
        offs [block!] "instances offsets"
    ][
        make self [
            _obj: obj
            _offsets: offs
        ]
    ]   
    pane_function: func [face index] [
        if integer? index [
            if index <= length? _offsets [
                _obj/offset: to-pair reduce [_offsets/:index/x _offsets/:index/y]
                _obj
            ]
        ]
    ]   
]
```

Code for main layout is:

```
_inst: _instantiator/new reduce b [0x0 50x50 130x130] ;;3 b objects are created in the positions indicated in the pairs block
_lo: layout [
    mybox: box 500x500 white with [
        offset: 0x0     
        pane: get in _inst 'pane_function
    ]   
]
view center-face _lo
```